# VBA excel loop through a range to split name from column

Tags: excel, vba, string, loops

I am trying to loop through an entire range (column) in excel to give me an ID by splitting at the "_". This code works for a single row, but I'm not sure how to make it loop through the entire row. File name is the column A as seen below. There are 276 rows that I need to iterate through. It is obviously copying the same thing for 2-276, because I'm only selecting C2 as the range. It will output D28NQ5 for everything. If I change the range to C:C, it does not work.

```
Sub splitName()
  Dim ImageName As String
  Dim newImageName As String
  Dim ImageNameParts() As String
  Dim ID As String
  Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet

  Columns("A:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
  Range("B1").Value = "ID Temp"
  Range("A1").Value = "ID"

  ImageName = Range("C2")
  newImageName = Replace(ImageName, ".", "_")
  ImageNameParts = split(newImageName, "_")

  Range("B2:B276").Value = ImageNameParts(4)

  SensorID = Right(ImageNameParts(4), 6)

  Range("A2:A276").Value = ID

  Set sourceSheet = Sheet1
  sourceSheet.Range("B:C").EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub
```

File name

CV42231.A.10.1_BAM92D28NQ5.czi - Scene #0.txt

CV42231.A.10.1_BAM92D28NQ5.czi - Scene #0.txt

CV42231.A.10.1_BAM92D28NQ5.czi - Scene #1.txt

CV42231.A.10.1_BAM92D28NQ5.czi - Scene #1.txt

CV42231.A.10.1_BAM92D28NQ5.czi - Scene #0.txt

CV42231.A.10.1_BAM92D28NP2.czi - Scene #0.txt

CV42231.A.10.1_BAM92D28NP2.czi - Scene #1.txt

CV42231.A.10.1_BAM92D28NP2.czi - Scene #1.txt

Comment: Why not just use the `TextToColumns` method?

Comment: `code` Sub ExampleSplit2()
    Dim objRange1 As Range

    Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A1").Value = "ID"
    
    'Set up the ranges
    Set objRange1 = Range("B2:B276")

    'Do the first parse
    objRange1.TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Range("A2"), _
      DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      Tab:=False, _
      Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=False, _
      Space:=False, _
      Other:=True, _
      OtherChar:="."

End Sub

Comment: I just tried doing that and it parses every single "."

Comment: Hey!!!!  Just kidding I think I got it to work. It'll take some editing to get it to not replace the current columns but I think it's right now. Thanks!